# Firebase displayName wont transfer to another page but mail does

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm pretty new to Firebase so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

So I'm working on a sign-up / login page. On the signup page, everything is working and every user who is created is assigned a displayName value that's coming from an input in the form.

```js
function signUp() {
  // Get DOM elements
  var displayName = document.getElementById("first_name");
  var emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
  var passInput = document.getElementById("password");
  var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

  // Add login event
  submitBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
    //Get email and password
    const email = emailInput.value;
    const pass = passInput.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    // Sign up
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser; 
      if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        var user = auth.currentUser;
        user.updateProfile({
          displayName: displayName.value
        });
      }
    });
}
```

However..

When the user logs in to a new page, only the email get transferred over, the displayName is set to null. I think its a problem with the "onAuthStateChanged" code in my login script.

```js
function displayUserInfo() {
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firbaseUser => {
  if (firbaseUser) {
   console.log(firbaseUser);
  }
  else {
   console.log("not logged in");
  }
 });
}
```

Would love to get some help on this :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function signUp() {
    // Get DOM elements
    var displayName = document.getElementById("first_name");
    var emailInput = document.getElementById("email");
    var passInput = document.getElementById("password");
    var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

    // Add login event
    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", e => {
        //Get email and password
        const email = emailInput.value;
        const pass = passInput.value;
        const auth = firebase.auth();
        // Sign up
        const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user);
            user.updateProfile({
                displayName: displayName.value
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. Using this did not give me a displayName after signup.